# Getting Started: Learning RoR for a ASP.Net MVC/C# Developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, ruby

I am an ASP.Net MVC / C# developer looking to get started with Ruby on Rails. Could you point me out to any books / tutorials which would help jump ships quickly.

I am familiar with MVC, Castle Active Record and jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just gone through this and looking for the best ways to learn ruby and rails I found the following most useful:

- http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails (covers Rails 3)
  I found this a good starting place to go through the basics of rails and while reading this I was able to follow along and build the application.
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
  Instead of building an application you get the vertical view of rails - i.e., sections to understand models, caching, views, layouts, etc.   This is a great resource to follow along and read the sections you are dealing with.
- http://www.railscasts.com
  As you come across something you need to implement - e.g., many to many relationships this site provides some great examples and walkthroughs.

As a C# developer you may be slightly confused by Ruby.  Here are the sites I recommend for learning Ruby:

- http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/Ruby/
  Although not formatted great - I found this one very useful to get the gist of Ruby syntax.
- http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/
  Another great easy to follow tutorial

Lastly just try out some code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed [Ruby on Rails for .NET Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470374950)

How quick you can jump ships is really dependent on how fast you pick up the Ruby language and a new IDE.   If you already know MVC and ActiveRecord you'll probably fly right along.

[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) is really really really cool.  Definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the rails world :) !

Here is some links that may interest you :

- There is a fun way to learn : railsforzombies.org
- You can watch great screencast at : railscasts.com
- You can find a free book here it is very complete : railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book
- I also found this : www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/1816/top-ruby-on-rails-tutorials

There should be a lot more.

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Ya right of now Ruby on Rails 3 is so proper among RoR developer. so get update on it.

Beginning Rails 3 - http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224334

Agile web development Rails 3 - http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

These two books are rocking new learning and making a step on RoR.

and if u want video tutorial, 
go for Railscasts and Teachmecode